# Getting second data attribute value from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am getting a row using one of many its data attribute and putting it into a variable now since I got the row in a variable i don't want to query dom again (if I am right ?). Then I want to get value of another data attribute from the variable but not sure how or what to search on Google ?

```
var aRow =  $("#fruittable tr[data-id=" + fruitID + "]");
```

Now I need `data-status` value, which is already added in `tr`

Can I do something like,

```
var status = aRow. // not sure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
var status = aRow.data('status')
```

Comment: Thank you, would it going to work with ie8 as well :-)

Comment: @CustomizedName: yes it will.you can also use ` aRow.attr('data-status')` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$(element).data()`:

```
var status = aRow.data('status');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
aRow.attr('data-status');
```

Or

```
aRow.data('status');
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("div").getAttribute('data-status')
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/0q2becpk/)

Answer (score 1):

You can access data-attribute of your variable by using this:

```
aRow.data('status');
```